# Unable to install pysiddhi

Tags: python, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

I get this message when I run `!pip install pysiddhi` on Spyder's IPython console.

```
Collecting pysiddhi
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pysiddhi (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pysiddhi
```

I'm trying to install the library on Windows using Spyder 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

It seems pySiddhi windows distribution is not available in pip.
I have created an [issue](https://github.com/siddhi-io/PySiddhi/issues/28) to track its progress.

Comment: If I need to install the library then, how do I do so without pip?